# Wifi 802.11ac dynamic channel width negotiation

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, ieee-802.1ax

Let's assume that

AP1 is on channel 40 width 80mhz,
AP2 is on channel 48 width 80mhz,
It overlaps.

As far as i understand 802.11ac has a functionality which detects width utilization per-frame and falls back to a much lower channel width. If AP1 detects AP2 and vice-versa they can go back to their main 20mhz and they might not overlap if they stay like that.

I never found a standard name for this functionality, there is 'Clear Channel Assessment', aruba calls it 'dynamic per packet negotiation of channel width', there is a lot more.

What i do not understand is how this could not cause issues like interference, for example, if they try to communicate at the same time at 80mhz

Comment: Have you checked the [original IEEE 802.11 standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68)? It's free after registration.

Comment: aren't APs supposed to do channel hopping?